# Creating an alert box with a button connected to a link

Tags: php, codeigniter, button, echo, alert

Salutations! I would like to create an alert box which echo a button connected to a link. I would like to do the whole thing using php. I would like to put that piece of code in my codeigniter controller function.

Here is a piece of code that can echo a button connected to a link:

```
echo '<a href="' . $url . '">Add to Google Contacts</a>';
```

Please help me to do my task. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Alert is a special kind of method which is only used for Showing some messages,with a button is attached.Only we can write text in it.If you want an alert box with your own components, design a new one yourself.But it will never become an alert box.By using jquery you can do this ..paste it.

Here is the Jquery code for dialog box,paste it.

```
<html>
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
    <style></style>
  </head>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src='template/js/jquery.textarea-expander.js'></script>
 <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
// <---- VENTAÑAS DE PARAMETERES---->
$(document).ready(function() { 
var regex,v,l,c,b,i,contapara=3;




$( "#wnd_Addparam" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            resizable:false,
            buttons: {
                "Link": function() {
                   location.href="http://www.google.com";
    return false;  },
                Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            close: {}
        });


                $( "#wnd_Addparam" ).dialog( "open" );


                    });
</script>
  <body>

<div id="wnd_Addparam" title="Information" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this will help you dr..

Comment: [Vijay](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4257136/vijay) - I know about echo ,a href, and button , but how to put make an alert box and put the button connected to link in it - using php code - thanks for ur help

Comment: [Vijay](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4257136/vijay) - I would like to create it in the controller and display it in the view - does it work

Answer (score 0):

You can use it with JavaScript to like,

```
echo "<a href='onclick='javascript:function(id)''></a>";
```

and the javascript you can use it by,

```
function(id)
{
    window.location.href("file_name.php")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<a href='#'><button onclick='".'alert("your alert message")'."'>Try it</button>";
```

Comment: above complete code is echo "<a href='#'><button onclick='".'alert("your alert message")'."'>Try it</button>";

Comment: [Vijaykanth](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3791154/vijaykanth-dondapati) - it doesn't work , my webpage becomes blank then

Comment: [Vijaykanth](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3791154/vijaykanth-dondapati) - thank you for help - btw, any other solution which works

Comment: echo "<a href='#'><button onclick='".'alert("your alert message")'."'>Try it</button>";

Comment: [Vijaykanth](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3791154/vijaykanth-dondapati) - Yes, this doesn't work. I have tried it. Thank you.